# Scala case class of array of maps

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary

I have a background in python and just learning scala. I want to declare a case class for data being read from database through spark. The data looks like the following:

```
|id  |  person_info
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |[{"fname":"john","lname":"doe","user_id":123,"dept":"hr"},{"fname":"jane","lname":"doe","user_id":456,"dept":"sales"}] 
| 2  |[{"fname":"ed","lname":"smith","user_id":345,"dept":"it"}]
```

I'm confused about `person_info` since it also has `user_id: Int`, this is what I've tried:

```
case class Person(id: Int, person_info: Array[Map[String, String]])
```

`person_info` was created in sql through:

```
SELECT id, named_struct("fname", t.first_name, "lname", t.lastname, "user_id": t.userid, "dept": t.department) as person_info FROM mytable t
```

Comment: Are the person_info fields always the same? If so, any of them may be missing, or all the must be always present?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: The fields are always the same, all must be always present

Comment: @DevEx since we don't have access to `mytable`, this does not count as a **MCVE**. Additionally what exactly is your question/problem? - how to turn such `DataFrame` into a typed `Dataset[Person]`? If so, then Himanshu's or mine answers should be enough. Or do you have any other problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the fields are always the same, you may use a nested case class instead.

```
final case class PersonInfoEntry(fname: String, lname: String, user_id: Int, dept: String)
final case class Person(id: Int, person_info: List[PersonInfoEntry])
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming person_info is valid Json object.  It can be converted to Array of object PersonDetails like below

```
case class PersonDetails(fname:String,lname:String,userId:Int,dept:String)
case class Person(id:Int,person_info:Array[PersonDetails])
```